# Fail to ssh to remote machine via hostname

Tags: linux, ssh, hostname

The problem is that I fail to SSH to a remote machine via its hostname, while using its IP works.

The hostname returned by command `hostname` is: `california_desert`
while the name returned by command `nslookup $IP_address` is: `pcpp3238782`. They did not match each other.

I think that's why I cannot connect to remote machine using its hostname.

I have checked `/etc/hosts`, `/etc/hostname`, `/etc/sysconfig/network`: all set the hostname to `california_desert`.

Checked with `/etc/resolve.conf`, the name server is set to the right one.

Also tried `strace` but no new clue.

Anybody can please help?

Comment: seems the issue can not resolve on local machine but to refresh DNS server, right?

Comment: No, you would need to contact the DNS server administrator and announce that computer known as pcpp3238782 should be rather called california_desert.

Comment: Yes, that's correct way, thank you buddy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the hostname and hosts files are only used for the computer they're on. In order for other computers to be able to use the hostname, it needs to be in the DNS zone for the domain.

Think of it like this - you get a phone, and it has a phone number 555-5555. You now know that to call California_desert, you need to dial 555-5555. But nobody else knows this. In order for others to know how to reach you, you need to register your phone number in the directory. DNS is that directory service.

Of course, you can also tell a friend that your number is 555-5555 and then they can call you directly without looking it up in the directory. For a unix system, this would be like adding the hostname and ip for California_desert to the hosts file on every server that wants to connect to it.

Comment: A more easier solution is to install a Zeroconf software like avahi on all computers. Then each computer announce its hostname automatically and can be pinged under TheHostname.local.

Comment: Thanks for your clear&detailed explanation, very helpful!

Comment: Very old question but another hint: california_desert is not allowed as hostname. Underscore `_` is not a valid character in DNS. Even with correct DNS lookup setting the host will not be reached by correctly configured peers.